# How can I use ActiveRecord on a database that has a column named 'attribute'? (DangerousAttributeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am accessing a database that I can't change and it has a column named `attribute` defined. Anytime I try to access an `attribute`, I get this exception:

attribute? is defined by ActiveRecord(ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError)

my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      def self.authenticate(username,password)
        where(:username => username, :value => password).first
      end
end
```

I found a plan on the ruby on rails mailing list for fix the problem but not work for me

```
  class << self
    def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
      return true if method_name == 'attribute'
      super
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but here are the details of my environment:

- ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision
  29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
- Rails
- 3.0.1 activerecord (3.0.1) activeresource (3.0.1)

UPDATE(solved):

PLAN A:

```
select("username, value").where(:username => username, :value => password).first
```

Comment: Is the exception about `attribute?` or `attribute`? Note where the question marks are.

Comment: the exception about `attribute?`.the column named `attribute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord queries support the `:select` parameter, which lets you define the fields you want returned to you as a string.

Usually people use something like:

```
:select => 'field1, field2'
```

If you know the raw query language for your database server, then you can use that in the select string. One of the options when selecting fields using SQL is to use the `as` modifier:

```
select field1 as the_first_field, field2 as the_second_field
```

and the database will return the fields using the new field names instead of the old field names. It's an easy way to manage legacy fields that are named in ways that conflict with Rails if your database supports that.

See "Learn to Love ActiveRecord's :select Parameter" in "[Five ActiveRecord Tips](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/five_activerecord_tips)" and "[Selecting Specific Fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)" in the Ruby on Rails Guides.

Here's an example from one of my Rails apps using the `rails console` to access my Postgres DB:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > dn = DomainName.first
 => #<DomainName id: 1, domain_name: "ip72-208-155-230.ph.ph.cox.net", created_at: "2010-04-20 05:53:22", updated_at: "2010-04-20 05:53:22"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > dn = DomainName.first(:select => 'id, domain_name as dn')
 => #<DomainName id: 1> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > dn['id']
 => 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > dn['dn']
 => "ip72-208-155-230.ph.ph.cox.net"
```

Comment: thank you.i know this plan,i use raw query language before.but sometime not safe.

Comment: This isn't using raw SQL, it's using the select statement which is only one part of a query. The `where` clause is what might be unsafe if you don't handle your parameters correctly.

Comment: But ActiveRecord is still going to try and make all the methods for the `attribute` column.

Comment: It won't see the attribute column in the response from the DB if its been renamed to something else in the `as` modifier. I've used this tactic several times to deal with legacy tables that had field name collisions with reserved words and methods.

Answer (score 1):

For column `x`, ActiveRecord creates `x`, `x=`, and `x?` methods. So, update your fix to this:

```
class << self
    def instance_method_already_implemented?(method_name)
        return true if method_name == 'attribute?'
        super
    end
end
```

Comment: changed and got a error `attribute_before_type_cast is defined by ActiveRecord`

Comment: What happens if you add `return true if method_name == 'attribute_before_type_cast'` to the list in `instance_method_already_implemented?`?

Comment: please see my update,solved it but many `return true if method_name ==`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use alias_attribute and thus use methods with different names.